# English verb for not agreeing with the decision and challenging it

Tags: word-request

What's the English verb for not agreeing with the decision and challenging it by, perhaps, submitting the complaint to some higher institution?

For example:

> Well, I officially failed the test, but I can't say that I am
> absolutely convinced that I have failed it. In fact, I'm quite
> surprised because it was really easy, especially the essay. One thing
> I find kind of funny, strange and very disappointing is that they
> don't give out the written essays with their corrections. Had they
> done that, I would have at least been able to see exactly where I had
> failed. But since they don't, it leaves some room for speculations
> that they have their own hidden quotas that they follow arbitrarily.
> This is a shady area. In the place where I studied before things were
> more transparent. The essays were given out along with the announcement
> of the results, so you can see for yourself how good or how pathetic
> you were on that test. And, in fact, you even had the right to
> ________________ the results within one week after the results announcement in case you disagreed.

Comment: You have some good answers below, so I'll just quickly add another option: "protest".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [**appeal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal), [**contest**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contest), or [**dispute**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispute).

**Appeal** is commonly used in the context of challenging court decisions by taking them to a higher court, but it could be used in an academic setting as well.

**Contest** essentially means challenge, but doesn't have a specific institutional sense associated with it.

**Dispute** also means challenge, and is often used in the context of transactions--if a charge on your credit card looked suspicious you would dispute it with the bank. It could also be applied here.

Comment: Can 'appeal' be a transitive verb? Will it fit my example, that is, can I say 'You had the right to appeal the results' or will it sound awkward?

Comment: @brilliant Yes, you can say that and it will sounds perfectly normal. You can appeal a decision or a result or a grade. Here's a link from a college about appealing grades: https://laccd.edu/Departments/PersonnelCommission/jobapp-center/Pages/Exam-Appeal-Process.aspx

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Appeal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appeal)

> a request made to a court of law or to someone in authority to change a previous decision:

Comment: Is 'appeal' a transitive verb? Will it really fit my example, that is, can I really say 'You had the right to appeal the results'?

Comment: Yes, it is transitive.

Comment: I see. Thank you!